# Reorder lines that match string in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have the output of a previous command that looks like this:

```
foo 1 some-string
    P another-string
bar 5 and-another-string
```

I want to move all lines containing `P` with one or more spaces before/after to the top while keeping the order of the other lines, e.g.:

```
    P another-string
foo 1 some-string
bar 5 and-another-string
```

The number of lines is not known. If possible it should be plain bash or `sed`.

Comment: How do you define column? What is the separator? Are multiple consecutive separators equivalent to a single one? Why no `awk`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good questions, after thinking about them I just recognized I can simplify the question: Ignore columns, it’s only about lines containing P with one or more space before/after.  The script so far only uses bash and sed and I’d prefer to not use another tool. But ok if it’s the obvious choice and much simpler.

Comment: Please clarify if both `X XPX X` and `X P X` are to be taken into account as having one or more spaces before/after.

Comment: @Quasimodo only `X P X`. Your answer works perfectly, many thanks! Also thanks for the detailed explanation of every step!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '
/ P /p   #If line contains " P ", print it
/ P /!H  #Else, append it to hold space
${       #On last line
  x      #Exchange hold space with pattern space
  s|\n|| #Remove first extra newline
  p      #Print
}' file
```

Sample execution with an equivalent one-liner:

```
$ cat file
foo 1 some-string
    P another-string
bar 5 and-another-string
APstring
    A P string
ipsum
ARP
    P VC
$ sed -n '/ P /p;/ P /!H;${x;s|\n||;p;}' file
    P another-string
    A P string
    P VC
foo 1 some-string
bar 5 and-another-string
APstring
ipsum
ARP
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirement to move all lines containing P with one or more spaces before/after to the top while keeping the order of the other lines, I would use `grep`:

```
{ grep '  *P  *' file; grep -v '  *P  *' file; }
```

Comment: Thanks, like the simplicity of this approach, although I think it only works with input from file. The `sed` solution can also be used with a pipe.